# MongoDB native driver fails silently when called in an async loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await

I am having a problem using the MongoDB client for Nodejs (3.0.4), with Node (v9.8.0).
The issue is that when I run a query against a database, it works when it is called one time, but not when it is called under a loop.

See the following code:

```
'use strict';

// Load modules
const Mongo       = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = Mongo.MongoClient;


async function runOnce() {
    let result = await runBasicMongoQuery();
    console.log(result);

    process.exit(0);

}

async function runManyTimes() {

    [1,2,3,4,5].forEach(async (x) => {

        let result = await runBasicMongoQuery();
        console.log(result);
    });

    process.exit(0);
}



async function runBasicMongoQuery() {

    try {
        console.log(`Creating client:`);
        let client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
        console.log(`\tclient: ${!!client}`);

        console.log(`Creating db:`);
        let db     = client.db();
        console.log(`\tdb: ${!!db}`);

        console.log(`Retrieve collection:`);
        let coll   = db.collection('temp');
        console.log(`\tcoll: ${!!coll}`);

        console.log(`Run Query:`);
        let result = await coll.find({ name: 'me' }).sort({ name: 1 }).toArray();
        console.log(`\tresult: ${!!result}`);

        return result;
    } catch(err) {

        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

When I run the function `runOnce()` I get a successful execution:

> ```
> Creating client:
>         client: true  
> Creating db:
>         db: true 
> Retrieve collection:
>         coll: true 
> Run Query:
>         result: [ { _id: 5aabfc0763abc840a19d927c, name: 'me' } ]
> ```

When I run the command `runManyTimes()` I get the following response:

> ```
> Creating client:
> Creating client:
> Creating client:
> Creating client:
> Creating client:
> ```

Notice that this fails silently at the MongoClient.connect(...).  No error raised, no nothing.

Why is this failing when invoking the command inside a loop that uses async / await?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about MongoDB, but about any async call you do inside a `.forEach()` loop, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop).

In your particular case I don't think it's failing, `process.exit(0)` is just forcing the process to exit before you're getting back the result.

Comment: Actually it was all about the forEach not working on async.   It never brings a result, just fails silently.  Your answer solved the issue.   Thanks!